# Can word list be made in single line instead of one in each line

Tags: microsoft-word

Instead of having list numbering or bullets like

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue

Where every number/bullets in a new line. I want this list in a single-line/paragraph like

1. Red 2. Green 3. Blue

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a table:

1. Insert a one row table with x number of items as columns (in your example, it will be 3 columns).
2. Enter the items in each cell.
3. Select the whole table, then select the numbered list.
4. Set the borders of the table to None. Resize the table's width. This will be the result.

[image: List items inside a one-row table]

Answer (score 1):

Word can automatically number items in the document such as figures,
tables, or illustrations. Word will automatically updates the numbers
when reordered so that they stay in order.

To sequentially number items in your text, follow these steps:

- Position the insertion point where you want the sequential number to appear
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
  to insert field brackets,leaving the insertion point between the brackets
- Type `seq`  followed by some name that should be the same for all items
  in the sequence (here I chose "test"):

  [image]
- Press F9 to update the field information, to replace the text with
  sequential numbers:

  [image]
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to display again the
  fields instead of the numbers, if required.